# Add extra table or just pass the foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have a doubt about this. I have 2 tables

**Ordered_products**

- ordered_product_id
- product_id
- quantity
- price_charged

**Ordered_items**

- ordered_item_id
- item_id
- unit_of_measure
- box_type

Each ordered product can be composed by one or more items and one item has only one ordered product.

Which solution is better:

Sol 1: Just add as foreign key the ordered_product_id into ordered_items table. (http://cl.ly/image/0g3G2J231U0P)

Sol 2: Create a new table with ordered_product_id and ordered_items keys. (http://cl.ly/image/0Z1D1C1g0R3t)

Please give me any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution one is better.  The only time you need seperate table is for many to many relationships or when that table needs to store information specific to the relationship, like when it starts and ends.

With a one to many relationship, just add a column to the many table to point to its parent.  It makes joins easy and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. Don't create unnecessary tables.

Association tables are only used for many-to-many relations.